# dual boot windows 7, ubuntu - factory configuration issue

Tags: dual-boot

Few years ago, I configured my laptop in dual boot (windows 7/ubuntu).

I recently tried to return to factory configuration through windows 7 in order to clean my computer and get rid off the ubuntu partition.

It didn’t work !

Linux is still here, and when I launch it, the following message appears :
« The disk drive for /windows is not ready yet or not present. Continue to wait, or Press S to skip mounting or M for manual recovery. »

If I press « S », ubuntu starts normally.

When I start the installation of windows 7, at the end of the last step, the following message appears :
« error : no such device: 80DC8267DC825776 setting partition type to Ox27
press any key to continue ».

I cannot use windows 7 anymore…

I would like to make windows 7 works again without having to re-install it because I do not have any windows 7 back-up.

(I would prefer also to get rid of ubuntu but if it is simpler to keep it, it is ok).

Thanks for your help !

Comment: sounds like you deleted Windows instead of Ubuntu. do you have a Windows install disk?

Comment: Unfortunately, I haven't.
Maybe I deleted a file that was linked to the both partitions, or something like that.

I wonder if I can restore what I deleted, or maybe delete ubuntu if it is the cause of the error message.